# My Java program is outputting the wrong answer when finding tax for a salary

Tags: java

There is no tax on the first 20% of salary entered. i.e for 20000..it would tax for 16000 with 10% on 15000 and 20% on the remaining 1000 which would be 1700 total tax. My program incorrectly outputs 14500....

```
import java.util.*;
public class taxable {


    public static void main (String[] args) {
     Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Enter your salary:");
     double salary=in.nextDouble();
     double taxDue=0;
     double tempTaxDue=0;
     if (salary < 15000) {
     System.out.println("No tax applicable");
     }else if 
     (salary >=15000 && salary <20000) {
     taxDue=(15000*0.1);
     }else if 
     (salary >=20000 && salary <=35000) {
     tempTaxDue=(salary*0.8);
     taxDue=15000*0.1+tempTaxDue-15000*0.2;
     }else if
     (salary > 35000) {
     tempTaxDue=salary*0.8;
     taxDue=(15000*0.1)+(20000*0.2)+(tempTaxDue-35000*0.35);
     taxDue=(salary*0.8)+(20000*0.2)+(salary-35000*0.35);
     }
     System.out.printf("The amount of tax due is: " + taxDue + "    ");
     double avTaxRate;
     avTaxRate=taxDue/salary*100;
     System.out.printf("The average tax rate: " + avTaxRate + "%%");

}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

When dividing integer values, always check for floating point division - `10/100` will be `0` by Java integer division terms, `10.0/100` circumcises this.

Comment: I changed the code to (salary >=15000 && salary <20000) { taxDue=15000*0.1; and I still get the wrong answer...

Comment: I just put the entire code there..although it compiles with no errors.

Comment: Clearly the second if-statement applies also, that's where your wrong calculation origins.

Comment: Check the if-condition. The third if surely should apply for amounts >= 20000 and <= 35000.

Comment: Ok I made that change & edited the above code..can you re-check the above code because the error persists..

Comment: Don't prepend if-statements with ";"!

Comment: On spot. Also indent your code properly, learn about else if chains and how to use `printf`, etc. Look for good books on basic Java Programming.

Comment: Ok I tried something with the code..can you guys check my edited comment and code above and see what the problem is now?

Comment: `if (salary < 15000); {`
**Don't postfix if with ";"!**

Comment: C:\Users\Bryce\Desktop\1504\taxable.java:22: error: not a statement
        (salary > 35000) {
        ^
C:\Users\Bryce\Desktop\1504\taxable.java:22: error: ';' expected
        (salary > 35000) {

Comment: Please learn how to compile your source code and cope with obvious compiling errors.

Answer (score 2):

To get 10% out of something either divide it by `10.0` or multiply by `0.1`.

```
taxDue = 15000 * 0.1;
```

But the biggest hidden problem here is you shouldn't use double to represent money. Use `BigDecimal` instead.

Why? Just for fun, let's calculate 10% taxes over `1500`?

```
double dValue = 15001;
double dTaxes = 15001 * 0.1;
System.out.println("Taxes with double: " + dTaxes);

// Taxes with double: 1500.1000000000001
```

Precision error -> Small, but it is there `0.0000000000001`.

`BigDecimal` to the rescue:

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("15001");
BigDecimal taxes = value.multiply(new BigDecimal("0.1"));
System.out.println("Taxes with BigDecimal: " + taxes);

// Taxes with BigDecimal: 1500.1
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/th7Vyp).

Comment: Good job for spotting the `double` instead of `BigDecimal`. +1

Comment: I changed the code to (salary >=15000 && salary <20000) {
      taxDue=15000*0.1); and I still get the wrong answer...

Comment: Ok I edited everything to *0.1 etc instead of 10/10 etc. But I still get the wrong answer..I just uploaded the entire code (along with the edits u suggested..will add the BigDecimal changes afterwards). Can u see why I still don't get 1500 & why I'm getting 18750.0

Comment: New to java so bear with me..now I put the else if and it "else without if"---------System.out.println("No tax applicable");
      }if
      (salary >=15000 && salary <20000); {
      taxDue=(15000*0.1);
      }else if
      (salary >=20000 && salary <=35000); {
      tempTaxDue=(salary*0.8);
      taxDue=15000*0.1+tempTaxDue-15000*0.2;
      }else if 
        (salary > 35000); {
        tempTaxDue=salary*0.8;

Comment: I did and solved the errors..now I have no errors..but its still giving me the wrong output. The program doesn't charge tax on the first 20% of a salary i.e for 20000, it would be 15000 * 10% = 1500 + the remaining 1000 * 20% which would total 1700. But my program gives 14500 as the answer....

Answer (score 0):

You have to use casting when you trying to assign to double variable some division, instead:

> taxDue=15000*(10/100);

smt as make one of divisor double value:

> taxDue = 15000.0 * (10.0 / 100);

Comment: I changed the code to (salary >=15000 && salary <20000) { taxDue=15000*0.1; and I still get the wrong answer...